# Установка java EE на Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Решил перейти на ОС Ubuntu. Столкнулся с массой проблем. Прошу помощи в нахождении адекватного мануала по установке java EE от Sun (не OpenJDK).  Можно на английском, я не привередлив. Мои действия:

1. Cкачал [на сайте oracle.sun](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-6u27-web-dl-458979.html) java EE c JDK
2. При помощи команды sudo sh /путь/файл.sh выдало следующее

   > `Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME`
3. [Скачал jre](java.sun.com)
4. Установил, благо инструкция как установить jre есть на сайте
5. Проверил java -version - ссылается на встроенный с убунтой openJDK
6. Прописал в самом низу файла .bashrc   JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jre1.6.0_27/
7. При проверке echo $JAVA_HOME выдало /opt/java/jre1.6.027/
8. Попробовал повторить пункт 2 - выдало то же самое.

Если что делаю неправильно, поправьте.

**UPDATE**
Устнавил java jdk, прописал в .bashrc

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jre1.6.0_27/  
export PATH=/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin:$PATH
```

При проверке `-version` выводит то, что надо. Теперь пытаюсь установить java_ee без jdk, формат файла .sh. Выводит:

> `Could not locate a suitable jar utility.  Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME`

**UPDATE 2**
неправильно задавал команду, вместо sudo sh /путь/файл.sh надо было вызывать /путь/файл.sh

Всем спасибо кто откликнулся.

Answer (score 1):

а ведь можно было сделать всего лишь.

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

отучатся надо от windows привычек

Comment: sudo apt-get remove openjdk 
удалил все
sudo apt-get install sun-javadb может установить только это

Comment: открыл репозитории каноникал и нашел там то, что вы имели ввиду

Answer (score 1):

Ну пропишите путь к исполнимому файлу...

cd /usr/bin

ln -s /opt/java/jre1.6.027/bin/java

Comment: попробовал, не получилось

Answer (score 1):

"...and accessible in your `PATH` or by..." - вот и добавьте `/opt/java/jre1.6.0_27/bin` в `PATH`. При запуске `java` из командной строки ОС находит исполяемый файл, просматривая директории в переменной `PATH`. `JAVA_HOME` же используется некоторыми приложениями (например, Apache Tomcat) при поиске JRE.

Comment: выводит то же самое

Comment: не исключено, что исполняемый файл от OpenJDK находится в PATH раньше вашего - вы путь к новому JRE добавили в начало?

Comment: openJDK удален с системы